# Why is 1+1=0 in a finite field F={0,1}?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|cc|}
\hline
+& 0& 1\\
\hline
0& 0& 1\\
1& 1& 0\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
"feels" right, but how can you prove that $1+1=0$? What is the reason? I assume that due to $F \times F \rightarrow F$, the result of $1+1$ must be within the field F after all.

I'm looking for a logical explanation.

Comment: You can't prove it, it's by definition. At best you can ask for the motivation behind this definition.

Comment: For $\{0,1\}$ to be a group, $1$ must have an additive inverse $x$ for which $1+x = 0$. $x$ can't be $0$ because $1+0=1$, so $x$ must be $1$
.

Comment: If $1+1=1$ (the only choice since you refuse to consider the possibility that $1+1=0$), then, on subtracting $1$ from both sides, we arrive at $1=0$ which is not permitted by those who insist that in a field the multiplicative identity $1$ must be different from the additive identity $0$.

Comment: previous comments are right, but also to say that $0$ represents all even integers, and $1$ represents all odd ones (in the usual way where $F=\Bbb Z_2$ comes from). So, $1+1=2$, but $2=0$ in this model.

Comment: @GitGud: You seem to be claiming there is more than one field with two elements.

Comment: There are infinitely many, but I'm not claiming that.

Comment: @Dilip: Even if you allow the null ring to be a field, you can't have $1=0$ once you have decided on $1+1\ne 0$ yet $1+1=1$.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Recall the two axioms about addition:

1. There exists a unique element $0$ such that for every $x$, $x+0=x$.
2. For each element $x$ there exists a unique element $y$ such that $x+y=0$.

If $1+1=1$ it has to be the case that $1+0=0$. But in that case you just reversed the roles of $0$ and $1$, as dictated by the axioms. That's fine, and it still defines a group structure, but it's easier to just relabel them to the traditional roles, where $0$ is the additive unit.

So if $1+1\neq 1$, it has to be the case that $1+1=0$.

Comment: Ah yes. I should have re-looked-up these two axioms our prof gave us. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

As a Finite Field, the distribute law must hold:
The distributive law holds: (a+b) · c = a · c+b · c for all a,b, c ∈ F.
You can chose 1 or 0.

Now, consider Boolean Logic.
Using the Or operator, then 1 is the correct answer. 0,1,1,1
If Exclusive Or, then 0,1,1,0 (as you have in your table)